# Is a class "cannot be subclassed" implied by "composed solely of static members"?

Tags: c#, class, oop, static, subclass

in C# in a nutshell,

> A class can be marked  `static` , indicating that it must be composed
>   solely of static members and cannot be subclassed.

- Is "cannot be subclassed" implied by "composed solely of static members"?
- If a class is composed solely of static members but not declared with `static`, is it effectively a static class? Can it be subclassed?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like this would be trivial to test..

Comment: Although technically, all non-static classes have at least the implicit parameterless constructor, therefore there is no such thing as a non-static class with no non-static members.

Answer (score 3):

**Is "cannot be subclassed" implied by "composed solely of static members"?**

Nope

**If a class is composed solely of static members but not declared with static, is it effectively a static class? Can it be subclassed?**

it is still a normal class and can be subclassed (not discussing the sealed classes)